# Unity 3.5 not resolving controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I have taken the following example code from the Unity documentation, and yet a basic controller can't be instantiated with a service implementation as a required constructor dependency.

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterTypes(
         AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
         WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
         WithName.TypeName,
         WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
}
```

This gives the error Exception information:

> Exception type: ResolutionFailedException Exception message:
>   Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "[XXX].Controllers.HomeController", name = "(none)". Exception
>   occurred while: Calling constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.CurrentInterceptionRequest
>   interceptionRequest,
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InjectionPolicy[]
>   policies, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container).
>   Exception is: ArgumentException - Type passed must be an interface

This is an MVC5 application and i have the latest Nuget packages for Unity and the bootstrapper

Comment: Are you using Unity interception?

Comment: This was the out the box configuration from the Nuget setup

Answer (score 0):

in order to get this working we switched the WithName parameter to use Default as the passed value.